# Send column names that contain a certain string to a list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe that contains columns like:

```
df

        a   b   c   d   a_main   b_main   c_main   d_main
row
row2
row3
```

I would like the column names that contain `_main` sent to a list. such as:

```
collist = ['a_main'  , 'b_main'  , 'c_main'  , 'd_main']
```

How best could I do that? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try via `filter()` method:

```
collist=df.filter(like='_main').columns.tolist()
```

**OR**

Via boolean masking:

```
collist=df.columns[df.columns.str.endswith('_main')].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
# reading in the data file
df = pd.read_csv('your_data_file.csv')

# making a list of all columns in the data file
columns_list = df.columns.to_list()

# filtering out columns with '_main' and appending to a new list
main_columns_list = []
for item in columns_list:
    if '_main' in item:
        main_columns_list.append(item)

print(main_columns_list)
```